# How to remove the downloaded OS X El Capitan from App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I downloaded OS X El Capitan from the app store to create a bootable usb drive and now that I am done, I dont know how to delete it. There is no un-install option in the app store.

How can I delete the downloaded OS X from my macbook?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very easy....

### Using Terminal

Type the following command:

`rm -rf /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/`

This will remove the the install and sub-folders for the El Capitan installer.

### Using Finder

Open the Applications Folder by navigating to it or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.  Select the *Install OS X App* and <kbd>Control</kbd> Click or right click and select *Move to Trash*

[image]

That's it.  The installer has been removed!